# Using `raw_id_fields` to select related objects in the admin

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Item` that has a foreign key pointing to `Category`.

From the `Category` admin page, I would like to be able to choose existing `Item` objects and modify them too.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, related_name="items")

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)
```

I have tried setting up the admin this way but it's simply displaying blank inlines and no magnifying glass or select dropdown to choose from existing `Item` instances.

```
class ItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Item
    allow_add = True
    raw_id_fields = ('category',)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    inlines = [
        ItemInline
    ]
    # also tried putting raw_id_fields = ('items',)  here
    # but it prompts an error saying 'CategoryAdmin.raw_id_fields' refers to field 'items' that is missing from model 'Category'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've misunderstood how the link works. Django doesn't offer a selection for reverse foreign keys. From the `Item` admin you could select the `Category` like that. But not the other way around.

One workaround would be to use a project that adds custom widgets such as [Django Tags Input](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tags-input) which adds a tag-like input field to your admin.

In this case the configuration would look something like this:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ... your other installed apps
    'tags_input',
)

TAGS_INPUT_MAPPINGS = {
    'your_app.Item': {
        'field': 'name',
    },
}
```

**admin.py**

```
from tags_input import admin as tags_input_admin

class CategoryAdmin(tags_input_admin.TagsInputAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import urls

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tags_input/', include('tags_input.urls', namespace='tags_input')),
    # ... other urls ...
)
```

PS: To easily create a fully functioning Django admin config try the [Django Admin Generator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-generator/) package.

Disclaimer: The linked projects are ones I wrote.

Comment: ok, fair enough. I thought I had seen this done somewhere once – but I'm probably remembering it wrong.

Comment: @rxdazn: there are ways around this actually, I've created a project which does this. I'll add an example